# ANDROID - How to search with EditText

Tags: java, android

I am working on an application where I would like to do a search via EditText. I have a few buttons and I would like to make it so that when text is entered into the EditText field, it automatically searches for the Text in that button. I'm using navigation_drawer, so the code is again a bit more complicated. I just wanted to ask if it's possible to search the text of a button and if so how.

What I want to do is that the text that is entered into EditText will act as a search, that is, the buttons with text that match the text that is in EditText will show up and the rest will disappear.

**fragment_morning.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_morning"
    tools:context="com.example.mcdonaldscoupons.MorningFragment">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_input_search"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="125dp"
        android:hint="Zadej název kupónu..."
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLength="100"
        android:maxLines="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/morning1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_input_search"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="McMuffin"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/morning2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/morning1"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:text="McMuffin Menu" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MorningFragment.java**

```
package com.example.mcdonaldscoupons;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;


public class MorningFragment extends Fragment {

    private EditText editText;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_morning, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        editText = view.findViewById(R.id.text_input_search);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                //Here goes code, right?
            }
        });

        view.findViewById(R.id.morning1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                builder1.setTitle("Typ kupónu");
                builder1.setMessage("Jak chceš kupón zobrazit?");
                builder1.setCancelable(true);

                builder1.setPositiveButton(
                        "Kód (Jen u tabletu)",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                                builder1.setTitle("Kód");
                                builder1.setMessage("Zadej prosím tento kód:\n132 900 23");
                                builder1.setCancelable(true);

                                builder1.setPositiveButton(
                                        "Hotovo!",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "GRATULUJU a přeji dobrou chuť :P",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        });
                                builder1.setNegativeButton(
                                        "Nefunguje",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Smůla :/\nMůžeš zkusit McDonald's aplikaci!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            }
                                        });
                                AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                                alert11.show();
                            }
                        });
                builder1.setNegativeButton(
                        "Kupón z aplikace",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Coming soon...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                builder1.setNeutralButton(
                        "Zrušit",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                alert11.show();
            }
        });
        view.findViewById(R.id.morning2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                builder1.setTitle("Typ kupónu");
                builder1.setMessage("Jak chceš kupón zobrazit?");
                builder1.setCancelable(true);

                builder1.setPositiveButton(
                        "Kód (Jen u tabletu)",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                                builder1.setTitle("Kód");
                                builder1.setMessage("Zadej prosím tento kód:\n132 852 34");
                                builder1.setCancelable(true);

                                builder1.setPositiveButton(
                                        "Hotovo!",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "GRATULUJU a přeji dobrou chuť :P",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        });
                                builder1.setNegativeButton(
                                        "Nefunguje",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Smůla :/\nMůžeš zkusit McDonald's aplikaci!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            }
                                        });
                                AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                                alert11.show();
                            }
                        });
                builder1.setNegativeButton(
                        "Kupón z aplikace",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Coming soon...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                builder1.setNeutralButton(
                        "Zrušit",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                alert11.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> textContent = new ArrayList();
Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.morning1);
Button button2 = findViewById(R.id.morning2);

textContent.clear();
textContent.add(button1.getText());
textContent.add(button2.getText());
```

And then in your

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
      if(textContent.contains(editText.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase()))
      //do your work
}
```

Comment: where do i have to put the first one?

Comment: and how do i make the part where buttons dissapears?

Comment: what do you mean by disappears? how the button will be disappeared?

Comment: Buttons that do not contain the search term will disappear and buttons that contain it will remain.